# Git log --stat show deleted folders

Tags: git

I am writing cool aliases to show my git history in different ways. I want to write one with `--stat` option, to see what files changed for each commit. However, it harms readability when whole packages are removed from the repo, since it displays the list of ALL files contained in said package (sub)folders as 'deleted'.

Is there a way to make the output more "human-readable" and show folders deletions instead of their content ?

I think git does not understand changes in directories, so this output makes sense, but maybe there is a workaround ? Like, configuring the command called to diff two commits ? I found how to configure the diff tool, but it takes two files so that's one step to late.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not keep track of folders at all. If you want to consolidate the output to show just a folder, you will need to write some kind of shell script to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a `--dirstat` option for `git log`, [consider the documentation `man git-log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) for the details.